# Baseboards or Laminate flooring first?

Tags: flooring, trim, baseboard, laminate-floor, laminate

I'm laying down new laminate flooring in a small condo and the current baseboards have got to go. They're old, ugly, dirty, and installed plain wrong. My question is: Do new baseboards go on before the laminate flooring? Or lay laminate planks first, then baseboards? It will eventually be a rental property, so I am thinking of baseboards, laminate planks, then quarter round to hide the gap. This way in the future it'll be easier to change out the floors if necessary. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your choice. Like tile under cabinets, or vertical vs horizontal drywall, you will get opinions both ways. Each side believes their method is best.

Your idea has some merit if you plan to have to replace the flooring occasionally to frequently. Removing the quarter-round to replace the floor would certainly be easier than removing the baseboards.

Sounds like you already have it figured out.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you put baseboards first, you'd have to tuck the laminate under them. Flooring first, baseboards second.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go planks then base boards. That's what holds it all together. Then no need for the added cost of quarter round.